# GraphViz set page width

Tags: width, graphviz, output

I'm using GraphViz to determine the controls location in my C# application.

But i'm not being able to give the graphViz dot generator the width of the output.

This are the paremeters of the dot file that im using

```
Digraph x {
    autosize=false;
    size="25.7,8.3!";
    resolution=100;
    node [shape=rect];
    (edges definitions comes here)
     ...
```

But seems to have no effect on the generated plaintext file.

Am I missing something do set the page width?

Regards

Answer (score 7):

I added `a -> b` to your example. Here's the plaintext output I get:

```
digraph x {
    graph [autosize=false, size="25.7,8.3!", resolution=100];
    node [label="\N", shape=rect];
    graph [bb="0,0,54,108"];
    a [pos="27,90", width=0.75, height=0.5];
    b [pos="27,18", width=0.75, height=0.5];
    a -> b [pos="e,27,36.104 27,71.697 27,63.983 27,54.712 27,46.112"];
}
```

As you can see, the `size` and `resolution` attributes are included in the output.

You may change the values of `size` and `resolution`, this won't change anything else than those attributes in the *plaintext* output. The positions of all nodes and edges are **relative** to the bounding box (`bb`) of the graph.

However, if you decide for example to output a *png*, graphviz will use this information to scale the bounding box according to your `size` and `resolution` attributes and calculate the final image size.

In this example, the resulting png will be 444 by 831 pixels (8.3 inches with a resolution of 100 dpi result in 830 pixels, the pixel on top is probably due to a rounding error).

You may find more detailed examples about `size` attribute and the resulting image size in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837414/63733).